# U-SQL trying to Extract a list of ints from nested JSON object

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to extract the ErrorReasons, along with the State and Id from this structure

```
{
    "id": "abcGuid",
    "RegistrationStatus": {
        "State": 2,
        "ErrorReasons": [
            1,2,3
        ]
    },
}
```

I can extract the Id, RegistrationStatus, and State, however I'm struggling with getting the list of ints out of the ErrorReasons list.

My starting Extract

```
@result =
    EXTRACT 
         [id] string
        ,[RegistrationStatus] string
    FROM @inputFileDaily
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();
```

Then I pull out the State, and ErrorReasons into their own fields

```
@pre =
    SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(RegistrationStatus) ["State"] AS State,
           JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(RegistrationStatus) ["ErrorReasons"] AS ErrorReasons_data
    FROM @result;

@pre =
    SELECT State,
           JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(ErrorReasons_data).Values AS ErrorReasons_Array
    FROM @pre;

@CreateJSONTuple =
    SELECT State,
           JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(ErrorReasons)["0"] AS ErrorReason
    FROM @pre
         CROSS APPLY
        EXPLODE(ErrorReasons_Array) AS c(ErrorReasons);
```

This of course gets nothing, cause it's looking for the field "0"
if I leave out the ["0"], then it complains about outputting a sqlmap<string,string> to csv.  I've tried .Value, .Values, ["1"], [0], [1]
.Values doesn't work for me either of course.
I feel I'm really close, just missing a key operation to pull out the list of values from Error Reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a little rubber ducking, and less over thinking it I figured it out,

```
@CreateJSONTuple = 
SELECT 
       A.ErrorReason AS Reason
FROM @pre
     CROSS APPLY
        EXPLODE (ErrorReasons_Array) AS A(ErrorReason);
```

and having found the correct documentation to follow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/data-types/built-in/complex-built-in-u-sql-types

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my answer.